# Detect canplaythrough of HTML Audio on mobile chrome when in Data connection

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, events, audio

I created a small web-app that uses Audio files as sound effects and background music, I noticed that when I run it on chrome under Wifi connection, it works perfectly, but when I switch to Data, some events would not fire at all in a timely fashion... they would eventually fire but after some interaction or calling of "play" method.

```
let v = new Audio();
v.preload = "auto";
v.src = "some mp3 file";
```

The events I watched

`loadstart 
suspend 
durationchanged 
loadedmetadata 
loadeddata 
canplay
canplaythrough`

On Wifi, they fire immediately in that sequence

On Data connection however, the first two fire, then nothing happens, until I call "**play**" down the road. After which, normal events fired, except that I noticed **stalled** being fired on Data only.

Is this behavior expected?

My question is, how can I detect "**canplaythrough**" or "**canplay**" or even "**loadeddata**" when in Mobile Data connection?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Obviously Android blocks automatic play of music and videos when connecting to Data. **canplaythrough** needs the audio to be preloaded or at least the meta data, which is blocked on Data.

Comment: `canplaythrough` won't fire if only metadata is loaded. From MDN: The `canplaythrough` event is fired when the user agent can play the media, and estimates that enough data has been loaded to play the media up to its end without having to stop for further buffering of content.

Comment: this question is old, I dont know if it changed, but back then if ur mobile is on Data, not even witchcraft could get it playing on load.